# Given a sine and cosine, what is the easiest way to determine when one of them is at its maximum amplitude?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a discrete-time signal

[image: sin(\omegan/N)+cos(\omegan/N)]

One easy way to determine when the sine reaches its peak, is by looking at when the cosine is crossing zero from positive to negative values. That works in the above case. I do have another signal of the form

[image: a[n](sin(\omegan/N)+cos(\omega*n/N))]

though, where I can't use this approach.

What is the easiest way to determine when one of them is reaching its maximum amplitude per period?

Comment: How about a derivative?

Comment: Oh it is actually a discrete signal. I should change the question. I was actually hoping for something easier to implement than a derivative.

Comment: Same procedure still applies. You can take the regular derivative or discrete derivative $x[n+1]-x[n]$

Comment: But how does that solve my problem? I already have the derivative of the sine, which is the cosine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\cos x + b\sin x\\
\sqrt {a^2+b^2}(\frac {a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos x + \frac {b}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}\sin x)$

Let $\phi = \arctan \frac {b}{a}$
$\sin \phi = \frac {b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\\
\cos \phi = \frac {a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$

$\sqrt {a^2+b^2}(\cos\phi \cos x + \sin\phi\sin x)\\
\sqrt {a^2+b^2}(\cos (x-\phi))$

The amplitude  is $\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$
The maximum occurs when $x = \arctan\frac{b}{a} + 2n\pi$

Comment: Thanks, I will need some time to try this out, but seems like it is what I am looking for

Comment: What is n standing for in 2*n*pi? Struggling to translate this to discrete-time

Comment: The function is periodic.